# Discord.js DiscordAPI Error: Unknown Emoji - Reacting to an Embed

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Here's my code:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith("!embed")) {
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor(0xffffff)
            .setFooter(`Page 1`)

        message.channel.send(':rewind::fast_forward:'); //this works

        //but this doesn't
        message.channel.send(embed).then(embedMessage => {
            embedMessage.react(":rewind:");
        });
});
```

I may have a hidden issue or not provided the correct parameters. I have looked at a [similar previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50849678/reacting-to-embeds-with-discord-js) and tried implementing it, but it didn't work, may be outdated.

Instead, I receive an error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Unknown Emoji
```

The emoji I'm using is provided in the standard emoji library, `:rewind:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discord.Js does not handle emojis with the Discord User Side `:rewind:` stuff. Discord.js is using unicode to send and receive emojis, except for custom emojis, IDs are used there instead.

This means that you should use the following code instead.

```
embedMessage.react("⏪");
```

The Unicode emojis can be found by "escaping" the emoji in Discord or using something like: https://getemoji.com/.

The escaping works by using `\` in front of the emoji, you might know this from `\n`. By putting `\:rewind:` the result will look as follows.

[image: Normal and Escaped Emoji]

When copying the Unicode emoji make sure to delete any spaces off of it.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use unicode emojis instead, Here is an example:

`embedMessage.react("⏪");`