# Discord.JS Message react with "standard" emojis

Tags: node.js, discord.js, bots

So... I've started a while ago with Discord.JS, and I have been searching and searching, but I just can't really find how to react to message with "standard" Discord emojis. I mean...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLeHx.png - those emojis.

I want to do something like this:

```
execute(client, message, args) {
    message.content.toLowerCase();

    message.channel.send('Something...').then(resource => {
        resource.react('${args}');
    });
}
```

args = 842839246934114324 (:smile: emoji)

Comment: From the [documentation](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html#reacting-to-messages) it seems like you can only input the unicode emojis. Look at this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66252724/15073477).

Answer (score 2):

**Get emoji by unicode symbol:**

You need to copy the unicode symbols (copy them from discord or from a website [like this one](https://getemoji.com/)):

And then just say `message.react('✅')`

You can get the unicode emojis from discord by sending the emoji as you noramlly would and prepending `\` before it. This will write the emoji as a unicode symbol which you can just copy into your code.

e.g.: instead of `:laughing:` type `\:laughing:`

**Get emoji by Id (only works with custom emojis):**

```js
const emoji = message.guild.emojis.resolve(id);
// OR
const emoji = client.emojis.resolve(id);

message.react(emoji);
```

Comment: `let varEmoji = message.guild.emojis.resolve(`842843970501607434`);
console.log(varEmoji);`

Result: null

Comment: Have you tried with `client.emojis.resolve()`

Comment: `guild.emojis.resolve()` might only be all the custom emojis in the guild

Comment: `let varEmoji = client.emojis.resolve(`842843970501607434`);
console.log(varEmoji);`
Same result, null

Comment: Ok...let me take a quick look at it

Comment: It think it looks like this only works for custom emojis

Comment: If I find a solution I'll post it, but I don't seem to be able to ;)

Comment: I have one more question then. why when i execute the query `INSERT INTO table (emoji) VALUES (''); in phpmyadmin there are question marks instead of emoji?

Comment: Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: I don't think so

Answer (score 0):

```
    message.chanenl.send("hi").then(msg=>{
    msg.react("ID")
  // OR
    msg.react("✅")
  // OR

  //V 11
   let emoji = client.emojis.get("ID")
  //V 12
   let emoji= client.emojis.cache.get("ID")
   if(emoji) return msg.react(emoji)
 })
```

Comment: it doesn't work, i tried and that's the result: `TypeError [EMOJI_TYPE]: Emoji must be a string or GuildEmoji/ReactionEmoji`

Comment: If you're trying to use the message ID version, then it'll only be for custom emojis.

Answer (score -1):

Adding onto MrCodingB's response:
Getting a native Unicode symbol from discord emojis is actually really easy; all you need to do is add an emoji and add a `\` in front of it, then send the message :)
Although this is possible I personally use getemoji.com.